# UICollectionViewController multiview error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have an issue with the `UICollectionViewController`. I start with the default view controller and i make a segue to a `UICollectionView`. When i click on the button which link to that collection i have that

**error** :

```
 could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

and the signal seems to be throw from that lign :

```
 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [UICollectionView reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Before you call either of these methods, you must tell the collection
>   view how to create the corresponding view if one does not already
>   exist. For this, you must register either a class or a nib file with
>   the collection view. For example, when registering cells, you use the
>   registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or
>   registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method. As part of the
>   registration process, you specify the reuse identifier that identifies
>   the purpose of the view. This is the same string you use when
>   dequeueing the view later.

So you need to register a class or nib to be able to deuqeue one.

To register:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[MyCellClass class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
```

To dequeue:

```
[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have an other problem : There is no signal anymore, but the images are not display. I begin the application with a view controller which has a button and a segue to the collectionView. Any idea ?? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the waiting. I have a new post with my problem here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399192/cells-are-hidden-using-collectionview