# Cells are hidden using CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, collectionview

I have a Navigation Controller pushing to a Collection View Controller. This collectionView has an `NSArray` of images, and I'm sure there are some elements in the collectionView using the method visibleCells.
But when I launch it there is no displaying cells.
Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"creme_brelee.jpg", @"egg_benedict.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg", @"green_tea.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", @"hamburger.jpg", @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg", @"starbucks_coffee.jpg", @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg", @"vegetable_curry.jpg", @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg", nil];
} 

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return images.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell;
[collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSArray *tab = [collectionView visibleCells];
for (int i = 0; i < [tab count]; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
}
[collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


return cell;
}
```

Where am I wrong ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: check if you actually have a `imageView` before you try to set the image. Insert `NSAssert(imageView, @"Must have a imageView");` in between `UIImageView *imageView = ...` and `imageView.image = ...`

Comment: `[collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` should be done in viewDidLoad or the likes, it should not be called each time cell is load, should be called only once.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. NSAssert throws an exception, how can i fix this to have an image ?
And i don't know how to call this method only once. I have to call that method on a collectionView rewrite, isn't it ?

Comment: Ok so I added the method with the register class in the viewDidLoad method, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to create a custom UICollectionViewCell subclass which has a UIImageView inside of it.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the imageView to see if its being cast to the correct type or that isn't null?

Comment: When i set the breakpoint on the imageView, i get this : imageView = (UIImageView *) 0x00000000. The images array has 16 objects according to the next breakpoint. Is the imageView null so ?

Comment: Perhaps you are intending to register a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass; but you are registering the `UICollectionViewCell` class itself with the `UICollectionView`.  This is a problem, because `UICollectionViewCell` does not have an `imageView` property, or any subview with a tag of 100 (AFAIK).  You should perform your view construction in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and register _that_ subclass with your collection view.